# how to make a box of nxn given in a url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a grid in an HTML. I have a number given in a URL and basis on that I need to make a grid of size n and then render it in HTML.

As an example, let's say my URL is like this `http://localhost/x/3`, then I need to make a grid of 3x3. URL can be in any format, there is no restriction on that. I don't need to use any third party libraries at all for this.

I am able to make a grid as shown in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/mWX7K/) but everything is manual as of now.

Below is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Below is my CSS:

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
}

div div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    outline: 1px solid;
    float: left;
}
```

What I need to do is, given a number in url, I need to render the grid of the same size in an HTML.

- How can I get a number from a url in javascript?
- And then generate grid basis on that number by rendering it in HTML.

Any jsfiddle example will help me to understand better.

Comment: @downvoter Can you explain why it was downvoted so that I can improve on? In a simple way it is just to make a grid in an HTML given a number in an URL.

Comment: It's more helpful including the code in your post where possible (and link to jsfiddle too if you want). It's possibly best broken down into two questions: 1) how can I get a number from a url in javascript, and 2) how to I generate a fixed number of 'div' tags using javascript.

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for explaining that. Appreciated, atleast somebody explained it. Let me improve my question.

Comment: You say no restriction on the URL format, so if it's like `/#/p2/3/bla4?num=5` what number would the grid be based on? Just the first numeric digit?

Comment: @Samurai good point, let's do like this. Any number after `x`, we will use that number to generate the grid, so url can be `http://localhost/x/3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- cells will be added here -->
</div>
```

Cells will be assigned `class="gridCell"` when created.

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
#container > .gridCell {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 1px solid;
}
```

To read the number from url based on the `base_url/x/num` format we can use something like `url.split("x/")[1]`. To make sure it doesn't go wrong we can have a default number just in case.

Then we'll need a function called `createGrid(n)` which takes a number and creates cells with width and height equal to `width of container/n` and append them to the container.

**jQuery:**

```
var defaultNum = 6;
var url = window.location.href;
var num = parseInt(url.split("x/")[1]) || defaultNum;
var container = $('#container');
var width = container.outerWidth();
createGrid(num);

function createGrid(n) {
    if(!$.isNumeric(n) || n <= 0)
        return;
    for(var i = 0; i < n*n; i++) {
        var dimension = width/n;
        var cell = $('<div/>').addClass('gridCell').css({
            'width': dimension + 'px',
            'height': dimension + 'px'
        });
        container.append(cell);
    }
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/cc5e06pn/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works fine on jsfiddle, I tested it just now. Now I am trying to put this together in my HTML file `abc.html`. After putting everything in my `abc.html` file and saved it on my desktop, when I hit it, I don't see it is generating grid, I am sure I am doing something wrong. Here is my gist - `https://gist.github.com/TechGeeky/82afd06a360fda306bb2`.

Comment: How do I open this `abc.html` in my browser so that it can take my parameter which I am passing.

Comment: 1. I used jQuery (since question was tagged with it), you need to include it before in the first script tag you already have: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: 2. Why does your html doesn't have a `head` tag?

Comment: 3. how to set up your url is a complete different thing. if you have abc.html and just want to add parameters you can either use `abc.html#5` or the more appropriate way add a query string like `abc.html?bla=5` ... either way we'll need to change getting the number from url in our code.

Comment: I just updated my gist. Take  a look and see whether I got it right this time or not. I saved it as `abc.html` on my desktop and when I opened it like this `file:///C:/Users/rjamal/Desktop/abc.html/x/3` on my browser, I don't see it is generating a grid. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Wrap the whole javascript bit inside document.ready and you'll be good to go: `<script type="text/javascript">$( document ).ready(function() {
 //add your codes here
});</script>`